# Most optimized way of searching a column for a set of keywords using Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to search a table for rows that match a set of keywords contained in a `List<string>` (there are currently 300 000 rows with texts anywhere from 100 to 50000 characters in length). The keywords list is usually 2-6 words (from a user-entered free text field).

I'm currently doing this like so:

```
List<string> wordsToFind = new List<string>() { "word1", "word2" };
var matches = db.Posts.Where(x => wordsToFind.All(z => x.Text.Contains(z)));
```

I have two questions concerning this.

1. Can this be done in a more efficient way?
2. Is there a nice way to get a % hit on the post. ie, if all keywords exist in the text it is a 100% match, if only 1 / 2 words match it is a 50% match (I want to use this to sort the results and show to the user).

The reason I am asking is that on a octacore SQL server with 16 Gb of ram, only running this database, it takes 20 seconds to search 8000 records for two words.

Just out of curiosity I checked the SQL this generates, maybe this is as efficient as it gets?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
  1 AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT
  N'word1' AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT
  1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable1]
UNION ALL
SELECT
  N'word2' AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT
  1 AS X) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
WHERE (NOT ((CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll1].[C1], [Extent1].[Text]) AS int)) > 0))
OR (CASE
  WHEN ((CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll1].[C1], [Extent1].[Text]) AS int)) > 0) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
  WHEN (NOT ((CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll1].[C1], [Extent1].[Text]) AS int)) > 0)) THEN CAST(0 AS bit)
END IS NULL))
```

Comment: Is the keyword list an extractable domain? (i.e. tag indexes on SO) or is it a user-entered free text field?

Comment: User entered free text. Navigation through tags/categories is also possible but separate from this.

Comment: `Contains` method does not use the index, that's why it's slow. You need to switch to `Full Text Search` capability of SQL Server for these kinds of operations.